# Nesting mysqli array and query functions

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link,$result));
```

Is this a correct PHP/mysqli statement or do I have to run the query first and then the array fetching in two separate statements?

Comment: Does your code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should do, what you want. Assuming the `$result`, despite the strange name, is really an SQL query string.

But make sure you have configured mysqli to throw exceptions on error. Otherwise in case of error you will have no means to get the error message.

*(Credits go to @Your Common Sense)*

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why do you think so?

Comment: Because result will be discarded and thus released all associated resources in destructor

Comment: OK, I see, because there's no reference to the results anymore, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So technically this code is all right.

Comment: You cannot as it's accepted. But you can edit it and then I can delete mine )

Comment: @YourCommonSense OK, edited. Thanks for correcting me.